# z-index not working with hover width effect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, z-index

I am creating a ruby on rails app and I have a five image side by side in one line... I want the width of the image to increase when I hover over an image...Now the width are working but the problem is the last image go to another side when I hover on any image..I tried a lot of way to add z-index but in vain...
try adding z-index from the script and from css with position relative and some more ways but still now working
here is my home.html.erb:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="width-r">
  <%= image_tag("wood1.jpg",class: "this h-h")  %>
  <%= image_tag("wood2.jpg",class: "this")  %>
  <%= image_tag("wood3.jpg",class: "this")  %>
  <%= image_tag("wood4.jpg",class: "this")  %>
  <%= image_tag("wood5.jpg",class: "this")  %>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 align="center"> Here comes the ads</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".this").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).animate({width: "25%"},"fast");
     });
     $(".this").mouseout(function(){
       $(this).animate({width: "20%"},"fast");
     });
   });
</script>
```

and here is my css/scss file :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
.this {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
}



.navbar-ma {
  /* remove space between the navbar and the images below */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}  

.jumbotron {
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Of course!! 5 *20% = 100% or 4*20% + 25% = 105% it means the space is to small for the last one !

Comment: yes I know but Instead I want the hover image to get z-index higher than the other images..

Comment: Why do you want a higher z-index is useless in this case !

Comment: I tried making the other 4 images 18.75% but it get with some problems as  the image go to the next line and then it back to the same line..so with z-index is better as the hover image will go above the other images

Comment: Wait until all the 4 images animation is done then assign the width to the last one ! this way the last image will not jump to the next line !

Comment: Please try this https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/L2Lmsjsa/ !

Comment: not good..now when I hover over the last one it go and stay in the next line....!!

Comment: Try to use a small percentage instead of 18.75%, like 10% for example, and increase it until you get the desired result.

Comment: same results...here is my code in production...you can see what I mean: https://agile-coast-64468.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works with elements that have a `position` style, i.e. `position: relative; position: absolute;` etc.

add `position: relative;` to `.this`

```
.this {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.this:hover{
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

you don't need to use JS for this. the `:hover` works when you hover over the html object (`transition: 0.25s;` sets the animation in CSS)

Comment: Please! this is not an answer to the OP's problem ! Maybe a comment !

Comment: @4lackof same problem...the last image go to the next line..!!

Comment: Hi anyway I solved it and put it above...your tips help me also with finding the problem so thank you...I add some divs and some css codes(include some of what you suggest) and it works now..

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem and want to put it here for anyone have the same problem..

I puts my images inside another div and add some css(some css get it from the guys that tried to help me in this question)... 
here is updates of my codes

home.html.erb:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="width-r">
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood1.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood2.jpg",class: "inside" ) %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood3.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood4.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood5.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
 <h1 align="center"> Here come the ads</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".inside").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css('z-index', '100');
        $(this).animate({width: "105%"},"slow");
      });
      $(".inside").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("z-index", '');
        $(this).animate({width: "100%"},"slow");
      });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my css/scss(you can also use the css way by uncomment the css code below and removing the js from the home page) :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.width-r {
  position: relative;
}

.this {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
  position: relative;

}
.inside {
  width: 100%;

  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
/*
.inside:hover {

  z-index:100;
  width: 110%;
}
*/
.navbar-ma {
  /* remove space between the navbar and the images below */
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}
```